# get class of object and instantiate new instance

Tags: java, reflection, subclass

I'm hoping to do something like:

```
SubClass c = var.getClass();
SuperClass varCopy = new SubClass();
```

In other words, I know what the superclass of varCopy will be at compile time, but I'm not sure which subclass will be instantiated. Is there a way to do this in Java?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do something along these lines.

```
Class<? extends SuperClass> clazz = var.getClass();
SuperClass varCopy = clazz.newInstance();
```

Note that the `clazz.newInstance()` will throw an IllegalAccessException if it does not have a default empty constructor.

Comment: +1 For more flexibility, you can use the Constructor http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

Comment: newInstance(), that was the method I needed!